# Finding the set $\text{com}(A)$ where $AB= BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}$. And I am looking for the set $\text{Com}(A) = \{B \in M_2 | AB = BA\}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $B=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$. Then 
$$AB=BA \text{ becomes } \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}.$$
Do the matrix multiplication and solve the resulting simultaneous equations.